# KnowRob Stack for RoboEarth in 11.10

Tags: ubuntu-oneiric, roboearth, knowrob, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I just updated the Ubuntu to 11.10 with the ros-electric and want to model 3D object with the RoboEarth. One of the dependencies of the RoboEarth is KnowRob but I found it's not available for 11.10. Thus I can't make the RoboEarth stack.

http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-electric-knowrob/

Could anyone tell me how can I install that dependency for RoboEarth for my Ubuntu 11.10?

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11989/knowrob-stack-for-roboearth-in-11.10/) by [XuechaoWei](https://answers.ros.org/users/1404/xuechaowei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've committed the Oneiric-compatible version of KnowRob: http://code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/tags/latest/

The official release is underway but it will take some time until the .deb packages are built and distributed. Until then, installing KnowRob from source should work.

Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2011-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [XuechaoWei](https://answers.ros.org/users/1404/xuechaowei/) on 2011-11-21**:
oh~Thank you very much for the Oneiric-compatible source code~

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

KnowRob does not build properly on Oneiric at the moment. There are only some minor details, but I did not have the time to look into that in more detail. I'm just setting up a virtual machine etc. to try it on Oneiric, and if things work out fine, there'll be binary packages soon. If you can provide patches to make the source compile on Oneiric, they are of course welcome.

Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1